# How do you simulate 3m of water for 30 minutes for IPX8 rating for waterpoofing with out using a 3ft deep body of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure

Idea I had for this was to use a column of water and to use external pressure source to press down on the water at the pressure of water at 3m plus atmospheric pressure. I’m trying to find a way to avoid using a 3m column of water as that is hard to replicate. So, I was trying to simulate the same conditions in a column of a much smaller height (ex 2 feet) and using an air compressor or water pump to add on the initial pressure. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Atmospheric pressure at sea level can generally be figured as 14.7 PSI. Each meter of water adds approximately 1.47 PSI. This gives a total pressure of 19.11 PSI absolute pressure for your simulated atmosphere plus 3 meter depth.